# running a package pytest with poetry

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am new to poetry and want to get it set-up with pytest. I have a package mylib in the following set-up

```
├── dist
│   ├── mylib-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── mylib-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── poetry.lock
├── mylib
│   ├── functions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── tests
    └── test_functions.py
```

in test_functions I have

```
import mylib
```

However, when I run

```
poetry run pytest
```

it complains about `mylib` not being included. I can run

```
pip install dist/mylib-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

but that clutters my python environment with mylib. I want to use that environment as well for other packages.

My question is: What is the proper way to work with poetry and pytest?

My underlying python environment is a clean pyenv python 3.8. Using pyproject.toml I create a project based virtual environment for mylib.

Comment: poetry install fixed this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to run [`poetry install`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install) to set up your dev environment. It will install all package and development requirements, and once that is done it will do a dev-install of your source code.

You only need to run it once, code changes will propagate directly and do not require running the install again.

---

If you have set up the virtual env that you want already, take care that it is activated when you run the install command. If you don't, `poetry` will try to create a new virtual env and use that, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I get `<project> does not contain any element` if I try to do `poetry install`. This is not a helpful error. What is it looking for?

Comment: In my case, the `does not contain any element` error was caused by incorrect setting of `packages` under the `[tool.poetry]` section of `pyproject.toml`. For example if it is set to `packages = [{include = "src"}]` then the `src/` folder needs to exist, otherwise the error is generated.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [specific way to run pytest](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-poetry-run):

```
poetry run pytest
```

I couldn't run it just running `pytest` with the virtual environment activated. Nothing happens when I run.

It just works when I prefix the `poetry` executable.

P.S.: Don't forget to add *pytest* as a dev dependency in your `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: Your P.S. saved me! I was running `poetry run pytest` but hadn't added pytest as a project dependency. As a result I guess it was running pytest from outside of my venv and resulting in a ModuleNotFoundError. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

FYI you also need pytest specified as a dev dependency in pyproject.toml.

If you don't have that, `poetry run` *will* find the pytest instance in your home env, but that instance *won't* find the venv. I don't think the documentation makes that very clear.