# poetry analog to `pip install -e .`

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

This should be sort of one of the first things to documentation should tell you, but it does not obviously do so. How do I install my own package with peotry?

With pip you do `pip install -e /path/to/folder/with/setup.py`. What is the corresponding command with peotry? `peotry install` only installs the dependencies, not the module itself.

Comment: I don't think there is really an equivalent, since Poetry installs everything in a virtual environment, and then uses `poetry run` to execute whatever script specify. That script will then use the virtual environment and your package installation directly, so that is how it runs with recent changes.

Comment: Uff, what kind of design decision is that. On top of that, I need to install the package so that my IDE can find it.

Comment: did you try running `poetry install`? It does a dev-install too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running a package pytest with poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783925/running-a-package-pytest-with-poetry)

Comment: It's a safe design decision: a virtual-env should ensures all dependencies will be installed and work, and it all stays out of the system's way.

Comment: Your question might be more: how to configure my IDE (which one?) to work with Poetry?

Comment: @9769953 I have my venv activated. Why do I need `peotry run` then?

Comment: @Arne No, does not help. I have run `peotry install` (within a conda environment).

Comment: @9769953 It is not about the IDE I think. For example, I want to open a python shell while having the venv activated within which I did `poetry install`. But when I do that, it does not find my own module which the `peotry install` command was for.

Comment: If you can point the IDE to the virtualenv, you might be in business.

Comment: @9769953 Nope, I of course did that.

Answer (score 8):

A `poetry install` will install the current project in editable mode.

This is a little bit hidden in the documentation at the end of this section: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install

For sure this can be improved.

Comment: I did `poetry insall`. This did not install the package itself. I cannot import it after doing `poetry install` and my IDE does not find the module either.

Comment: Than please update your post with the content of your pyproject.toml and show the folder structure of the project.